# Mongo Db find and retrieve a user and get all cards data

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express

following is my mongodb User document___

{
"name":"steve",
"email": "steve@sheild.com",
"password": "tnvddcnd",
"cards": [{
"tags": "card",
"user": "steve",
"bank": "bank of sheild",
"cardNo": 5152655,
"expiry": "2/21/2022",
"cvv": 512,
"pin": 5155
},
{
"tags": "card",
"user": "ironman",
"bank": "stark bank",
"cardNo": 56555,
"expiry": "2/21/2028",
"cvv": 256,
"pin": 6666}]
}

for every user ,I have cards store in array of cards. What i wanted is to find a user by email id which will come as query and then get the cards for that user

Comment: For your use case, you might write an aggregation query to pull the required document via email. Followed by that, if you are interested in any particular of the cards, you can unwind the cards array and project the required attributes as per your filter condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you use mongodb-driver

```
// find user by email and return cards:
user = await db.collection('User').findOne({email: "testemail@test.com"}, {projection: {cards: 1}});

// cards
user.cards
```

[Reference](https://docs.mongodb.com/drivers/node/usage-examples/findOne)